# Help with REST API CreateContacts Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I'm trying to add a contact through Postman to a Marketing Cloud Data Extension . When I run the `createcontacts` JSON file it shows me the error below but has 
a status `200 OK`.

Should the Data Access of the data extension be Read and write?

```
{
    "operationStatus": "FAIL",
    "rowsAffected": 0,
    "contactKey": "acruz@example.com",
    "contactID": -----,
    "contactTypeID": 0,
    "isNewContactKey": true,
    "requestServiceMessageID": "4da11e2f-f297-4213-8a61-------",
    "responseDateTime": "2020-04-02T13:44:03.6180429-06:00",
    "hasErrors": true,
    "resultMessages": [
        {
            "resultType": "Operational",
            "resultClass": "Error",
            "resultCode": "",
            "resultName": "",
            "message": "An exception occurred while processing the request item @ Index #0. [ReferenceID: b2ffcfda-79f5-4d9c-8925-9506048e3469]. "
        }
    ],
    "serviceMessageID": "d0a876d7-9b79-4330-8f00-934d937d4ffa"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please update your question to include the full Postman code?  The error message alone isn't enough to help troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: I am guessing you are using the exact example payload (`acruz@example.com`) from the docs. The issue is that the in order for this to be valid, you need to change the email to a valid domain (example.com is denied by list detective). This is even stated inside the docs, right above the example payload (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createContacts.htm)

Comment: That is the error you get for invalid or missing email address. Invalid email domains cause the error, but also if you try to create a new contact using only the Email Demographics attribute set without providing an email address.